# Java : not Serializable Exception

Tags: java, serialization

I am programming a game in Java (tetris-like) but I got this error when running it :

```
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.PoolPieces(Unknown Source)
at Fenetre.<init>(Fenetre.java:196)
at Score.lancerNewFenetre(Score.java:103)
```

So this error happens at the beginning, when I try to retrieve an Array of "Piece" from the server (Class "Partie" (Game)), to then set the pieces and be able to play. The code that makes the error occur is :

```
    try 
    {
        this.unpool = this.ninja.PoolPieces(this.id);
        System.out.println(unpool);
        this.setBoutons(this.unpool);
        System.out.println("boutons set");
    } 
    catch (RemoteException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It breaks at the first line, where "unpool" is a Piece[], "ninja" is my interface that I set at the beginning of the code, and "PoolPieces" is my method to get a pool of 3 pieces (Piece[]). Here is the code of the method "PoolPieces" :

```
public Piece[] PoolPieces(Integer id) 
{
    Integer rang = this.listejoueurs[id].getRang(id);
    Integer retour = rang + 1;
    this.listejoueurs[id].setRang(retour);
    this.leretourpieces = this.piecespartie[rang];
    return this.leretourpieces;
}
```

I have created a class "Joueur" (Player), and every player has a "rang" (rank). So, the avaible pieces are the same for all the players, and they retrieve the pool of pieces according to their progression in the game.
The "listejoueurs" is a Joueur[], it is an array containing the different players for the game.
The "id" is the identifier to link a client with a player : the first player added is added at place 0 in the array, and the id = 0 is sent to the client. The next player will have id = 1, and so on.
"leretourpiece" is my Piece[] that I want to return. It is taken from a Piece[][], created randomly at the beginning of the game. It is an array, of array of 3 Piece. "leretourpiece" gets the pool of piece according to the progression of the player (as explain above).

After looking for that error on internet, I implemented Serializable in barely every class, but nothing changed. The strange thing is also that something the error doesn't show up, and succeeds in getting the pool, maybe once over 10 intents or so, but then, when putting the pieces on the grid I have sme problems, misplacements, etc. (that may be an error in the code that puts the piece on the grid, I am not sure).

So I am quite stuck with that problem and I can't find where it comes from. Thank you very much in advance for the time taken to read this, and eventually help me :)

Comment: Okay, I did the change you suggested but the same error still comes out :/

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have related code block its hard to give clear answer. In some part of your code you are using `BufferedImage` as [instance variable](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm) and try to **serialize** that. Simply find the related code block and carry into method body as an image provider. (i.e. *getMyImage()*)

*If you can not find a solution, add related code block (where you use BufferedImage) into your question so I can update my answer*

**EDIT****
Can you please try this:

Remove **ImageIcon** references on Class **Fenetre**, below part:

```
private ImageIcon image1;
private ImageIcon image2;
private ImageIcon image3;
```

And replace this part:

```
 this.image1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(this.nompiece1 + ".png"));
        this.image2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(this.nompiece2 + ".png"));
        this.image3 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(this.nompiece3 + ".png"));
```

with:

```
ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(this.nompiece1 + ".png"));
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(this.nompiece2 + ".png"));
        ImageIcon image3 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(this.nompiece3 + ".png"));
```

Comment: Here is the main part of the code (except ActionListner because it is very long and I don't think it is the source of the error) :

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pbNDqvtV

(was too long for the comment)

Comment: The "Partie" (Game class) code :

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vaA7d1VP

Comment: @AlexandrevanWesel can you check my edit and try again?

Comment: @AlexandrevanWesel I dont think my edit will solve the problem, probably button will try to serialize image. you should check the question marked by EJP

Answer (score -1):

The object you are trying to manipulate via RMI holds a reference to a `BufferedImage` and, as the error message implies, `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` does not implement `java.io.Serializable`.

As is (unfortunately) often the case with Java, it is better to stay away from the provided Serializable mechanism an provide yours.

(For the record, Java designers actually regret having implemented it in the first place)

**Downvoters**: since you downvote faster than you check, let me save you some time: watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K__bKr5mGXY) of Brian Goetz (Java Language Architect) and at 20:59 have a good look at the slide that says "regretting serialization" and listen until to about 22:15.

For the rest of us, there are librairies out there, such as [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) which does it better, faster, safer.

Comment: I will try that asap and give you the feedback.

Comment: Citation please for your claim about the Java designers.

Comment: @EJP Sure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K__bKr5mGXY.

Comment: @EJP  Now you can give me my 2 points back :)

Comment: @EJP This question is not duplicate as I don't try to serialize a BufferImage. It is done directly on the client so there shouldn't be any problem. Moreover, in the thread you posted, there is clearly stated that ImageIcon ARE serializable, and it is what I use...

Comment: And Bruno I upvoted you for the help.